# GCC warning [Wuninitialized]

Tags: c++, gcc, gcc-warning

Why GCC 4.7 complains when instantiate a class inside a function (with a pointer)?

Bad:

```
#include "foo.h"

int fn () {
    Foo *foo;
    foo->method();

   return 0;
}
```

> main.cpp: In member function 'int foo()':
>   main.cpp:21:52: warning: 'fn' may be used uninitialized in this
>   function [-Wuninitialized]

Good:

```
#include "foo.h"

Foo *foo;

int fn () {
    foo->method();

   return 0;
}
```

Good:

```
#include "foo.h"

int fn () {
    Foo foo;
    foo.method();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Static variables are value-initialized, so the 2nd snippet doesn't cause a warning. For the rest, pick up a good book about C++.

Comment: Can you please take care to post errors exactly as they are reported by the compiler for the exact code that you've posted. "main.cpp: In member function 'int foo()': main.cpp:21:52: warning: 'fn' may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]" This makes no sense, `foo` is not a function let alone a member function and `fn` is not a variable.

Comment: It looks like the names `foo` and `fn` have been reversed in the error message you copied. Either that or C++ compiler messages have attained a new level of misdirection.

Comment: @Charles Bailey, There are a lot of extra code, so I left the only important

Comment: @Duglas: If you edit the code, you should re-compile and paste the exact output of the compiler for the edited code otherwise people will notice the discrepancies and won't trust that you've posted the actual code that you need help with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a difference between `Foo * foo;` and `Foo foo;` The first declares a *pointer* to a Foo, the second declares & invokes the default-constructor of a Foo.

EDIT: Maybe you meant to write `Foo * foo= new Foo();`, in order to allocate a `Foo` on the heap which can outlive the function call.

Answer (score 5):

The first (bad) one, foo is pointing to a garbage pointer. You could remove the warning by initializing it like `Foo* foo = NULL;` but then you'd get an error when you tried to dereference it (runtime error).

The second (good) one doesn't complain because C automatically initializes variables in the translation unit scope to NULL or 0 or the appropriate equivalent if they're not already initialized.

The last (good) one doesn't complain because you are calling a method on the object and the assignment of the function pointer is done by the compiler, similar but not the same as number 2. So the compiler already knows the address of the method `method` and has assigned that address to the appropriate location on the `Foo` struct.

Answer (score 2):

`Foo* foo; foo->method()` is ***never*** good. `foo` is an uninitialized pointer that potentially points to garbage and as such your code exhibits undefined behaviour. The *best* you can hope for is that the compiler warns or errors out on you. If not that, then atleast hope that the running programm *crashes*.

Answer (score 2):

In your bad example `foo` is a local variable with pointer type, which is not initialized automatically. The `class Foo`, in your correct example, *is* initialized using the default constructor.

Your first »good« example initializes the pointer with `0`, because `foo` is a global variable. It will result in *undefined behavior* at runtime, since `foo` does not point to an object.

Answer (score 2):

because, just as the warning says, it's uninitialized. there's no object yet. actually the value of foo in your first example is undefined. it will have the value that resides in the memory where foo lives.

to clarify, foo (which you see as a Foo*) is actually an int. the value of the int is supposed to be the address to an object of type Foo. to make it such, you have to assign it the address of a foo. one of doing this is to instantiate it with new:

```
Foo* foo = new Foo;
```

`new` returns the address where the new Foo object was created. this will remove your warning :)